# Phantom JS - clipRect - Javascript Help

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

i'm using phantom js to screen shot a page

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering

it has a feature called clipRect

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#clipRect_(object)

can someone show me how i would modify the following code to us clipRect so i only get a partial screenshot and not the whole thing?

```
if (phantom.state.length === 0) {
if (phantom.args.length !== 2) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    var address = phantom.args[0];
    phantom.state = 'rasterize';
    phantom.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    phantom.open(address);
}
} else {
    var output = phantom.args[1];
    phantom.sleep(200);
    phantom.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Comment: brew was installing the wrong version of phantomjs and the version it was installing doesn't support clipRect. Closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening is i was using brew and it was installing v 1.0.0 where clipRect and almost every other function wasn't supported as v 1.0.0 is the oldest version.

If you follow these instructions: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/BuildInstructions#Mac_OS_X

then right click on the complied file and click show/view contents (on mac) then copy the executable bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs to some directory in your PATH.

Feel free to post on here i'm monitoring this and i can help if needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to get a screenshot of a particular element, you could get the necessary information for `clipRect` from `getBoundingClientRect` as per the bottom of [this article](http://filosottile.github.io/taking-retina-screenshots-with-phantomjs/#bonus):

```
page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById(THE_ELEMENT_YOU_WANT).getBoundingClientRect(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html):

> **clipRect (object)**
>
> This property defines the rectangular area of the web page to be rasterized when render() is invoked. If no clipping rectangle is set, render() will process the entire web page.
>
> Example: `phantom.clipRect = { top: 14, left: 3, width: 400, height: 300 }`

So try setting `clipRect` right before you call `render`:

```
var output = phantom.args[1];
phantom.sleep(200);
phantom.clipRect = { top: 14, left: 3, width: 400, height: 300 }
phantom.render(output);
phantom.exit();
```

You'd have to figure out where the upper left corner (`top` and `left`) is and how big (`width` and `height`) you want the clipping rectangle to be.

You can probably set the `clipRect` any time before `render()` is called but start with that and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, what was happening is using bundle install was installing v 1.0.0 where clipRect and almost every other function wasn't supported as v 1.0.0 is the oldest version.

Comment: i was using Brew to install, not bundle install

Comment: @joel: So you had a version issue? Version issues are the stuff of nightmares.